# problem with pop up object list with visual-studio-2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm developing ASP.net project with C# using vs visual-studio-2008. when I drag drop asp control from tool box to the design view then I go to the code behind I should see the control in pop up object list. at the begin I had no problem but not when I drag and drop any new control I can not see it and even if I write it manually when give me an error this this name not exist.

Comment: Need more detail.  By "popup" do you mean Intellisense? 
You should accept some answers, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:
- Can you compile your code? Compilation errors often cause problems with intelli-sense
- Is your designer properly connected to the code behind?
- Try making a new WebForm to see if you have the same problems there
- Any DLL references that are broken?

Comment: Thank you Zyphrax for your reply. when I make new webform page I have no problem but still have same problem with old page. by the I'm using Ajax controls and I have no problem to compile the project if there is no code be-hide for the new controls.

Comment: There could be a small thing wrong with your Page tag at the top of the ASPX, the filenames or even in your project definition. I would rename the old page, and copy design code and code-behind code to the new (working) page. Make sure you don't copy the Page tag and class ... definition. Should save you a lot of trouble :)